# rain barrel diverter for 6x6 downspout

Tags: rain-barrel

We are planting a garden at our preschool, including a rain barrel painted by the kids. The downspouts on the school are 6 inches by 6 inches. All of the rain barrel diverters I have found are designed for 2x3 or 3x4 downspouts.

Does a diverter for a 6x6 downspout exist? If not, any suggestions on how to make one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it consider "the framing, plumbing or electrical aspects of building greenhouses, decks, or other structures (try Home Improvement instead)"

Comment: I think this is a very relevant topic for all gardeners as a way of conserving water.  I vote to keep it here

Comment: Those are huge down spouts. Also ask the question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

A metal shop or welding shop can produce one for you for around 30 bucks...depends on the shop...there is also another fun way to make a different kind of guidance system for the water coming out of the gutters.

A big thick antique (maybe) chain attached to the downspot coming from the gutter will 'hold' water to it as it flows into the barrel.  Very pretty.  If it is a major downpour the barrel itself will either catch the water and when full allow the water to splash out widely enough to not gouge a hole beneath the downspout.

Just an idea.  Otherwise, I've had specially made fittings for woodstoves for instance.  Look up Welders, Welding, Metal Smiths...tell them what you need and at least they will direct you to a shop that deals with making customized fittings.  I was amazed how inexpensive this was!